# Find current value of ODS ESCAPECHAR

Tags: sas

I am writing a macro to help create documentation which must use `ods escapechar`.  I need it to preserve whatever options/setting the original program used.  However, setting a new escape character in the macro overwrites the original program's escape character.  How can I change the escape character only for the duration of my macro?

Is there a table somewhere in SAS which stores the current `ods escapechar`?  My thought is to assign the current value to a macro variable and use that to reassign it once my process is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the escape sequence instead

```
(*ESC*)
```

Then you don't have to know or reset anything.

Comment: What happens if the text you want to write includes the current escape character?  Does it also get treated as starting a command? Like the trouble caused by text strings that had the split character in the old line printer days?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere around 9.3 (?) they added &SYSODSescapeChar:

```
%put &=SYSODSescapeChar ;
SYSODSESCAPECHAR=^
```

But since the generic `(*ESC*)` mentioned by data_null_ came first, I'm in the habit of using that, rather than do the save option / reset option / restore saved option dance.